# modificar un arraylist mediante la tabla

Tags: java

quiero modificar un arraylist que esta ya mostrada en la tabal, pero me piden descontar articulos. lo que quiero es descontar la cantidad del articulo a partir de la fila seleccionada en la tabla. mi arralist tiene esta informacion

cont_compras{codigo,articulo,costo,CANTIDAD,fecha};

ese es mi arraylist y quiero descontarla a traves de un textFiel digitado por techado, que me modifique la resta ..osea que CANTIDAD = cantidad_del_articulo - textFiel;

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si no agregas el codigo respectivo, un ejemplo, va a ser muy dificil ayudarte